# Refactor to generic method with select LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, refactoring

I will try to refactor this code snippet

```
if (e.Value is DoctorTechnicianDto doctorTechnician)
{
     if (exam.RecordingFiles.Select(d => d.Doctor).All(d => d.Id == doctorTechnician.Id))
     {
         return;
     }

     if (exam.RecordingFiles.Select(d => d.Doctor).Any(d => d.Id == doctorTechnician.Id))
     {
         ShowMessage(e);
         return;
     }
}
else if (e.Value is HospitalDepartment hospitalDepartment)
{
    if (exam.RecordingFiles.Select(d => d.HospitalDepartment).All(d => d.Id == hospitalDepartment.Id))
    {
        return;
    }

    if (exam.RecordingFiles.Select(d => d.HospitalDepartment).Any(d => d.Id == hospitalDepartment.Id))
    {
        ShowMessage(e);
        return;
    }
}
```

The main idea is to have a generic method that accept as input parameter the DTO (Doctor or HospitalDept) and made all the checks. The refactor is planned to avoid code repetition for other available DTOs.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: The thing is that you are attempting to access very specific properties on these DTO's...Is it possible to impose [generic constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) between these DTO's? ex. can they all be brought under a single interface that will expose exactly what properties you need? Otherwise within the generic method you will just end up spending a lot of time checking the types of each individually and it will defeat the purpose

Comment: @narish HospitalDepartment and Doctor still has a base class that is used in other part of the code for other DTOs, but the Id is a specific field for a these specific DTOs. I can try to move it to the base class, but I've to review other DTOs and investigate that this solution doesn't introduce side effects